# Read Access Violation opening file from proc LUA

Tags: file, lua, io, sas

I program in SAS and want to write a create an xml file using LUA

So first, I start `proc LUA` and pass the file name
;

```
%let file = \\ourCompany\ourTeam\ourProject\myFile.xml;

proc lua restart;
submit;
    local file_name = sas.symget("file")
    print (file_name)
```

--Next, I open the file for writing, write something and close it

```
    print('DEBUG: before opening')
    file = io.open (file_name, "w")
    print('DEBUG: after opening, before writing')
    file:write ("<test/>", "\n")
    print('DEBUG: after writing, before closing')
    file:close()
    print('DEBUG: after closing')
```

-- and of course stop LUA

```
endsubmit;
run;
```

/*This works: the file is created with this content

```
<test/>
```

But it results in the following messages in the log

```
NOTE: Lua initialized.
\\ourCompany\ourTeam\ourProject\myFile.xml
DEBUG: before opening
DEBUG: after opening, before writing
DEBUG: after writing, before closing

ERROR:  An exception has been encountered.
Please contact technical support and provide them with the following traceback information:

The SAS task name is [LUA (2)]
ERROR:  Read Access Violation LUA (2)
Exception occurred at (89400CB7)
Task Traceback
Address   Frame     (DBGHELP API Version 4.0 rev 5)
00007FFD89400CB7  000000000862F1F0  ntdll:RtlAllocateHeap+0x27
00000000084D2ACD  000000000862F1F8  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x81A8D
00000000084D0E7F  000000000862F250  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x7FE3F
00000000084D0D17  000000000862F280  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x7FCD7
00000000084CF711  000000000862F2B0  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x7E6D1
0000000008462609  000000000862F300  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x115C9
0000000008474A7D  000000000862F410  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x23A3D
0000000008485C7E  000000000862F530  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x34C3E
0000000008474349  000000000862F570  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x23309
00000000084788A4  000000000862F8D0  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x27864
0000000008478A9D  000000000862F940  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x27A5D
0000000008469746  000000000862F9A0  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x18706
00000000084523A2  000000000862F9F0  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x1362
000000000845224E  000000000862FB10  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x120E
00000000084529F4  000000000862FBF0  sasplua:tkvercn1+0x19B4
0000000001A489DB  000000000862FBF8  sashost:Main+0x10EBB
0000000001A4E61D  000000000862FF50  sashost:Main+0x16AFD
00007FFD875613F2  000000000862FF58  KERNEL32:BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
00007FFD893E54F4  000000000862FFD0  ntdll:RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

I have no idea if this is a pure LUA issue, or something related to `proc LUA` in SAS.

As the last DEBUG message is not printed, the problem seems to occur while closing the file. I tried a few different options for the `open` command and I tried removing the `io.write`, but that did not help.

Comment: which maintenance version are you using?  (`&sysvlong`).  This looks like something for SAS Support..

Comment: `%put &sysvlong;` prints `9.04.01M3P062415`

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked fine for me (on `SYSVLONG=9.04.01M3P062415`, `SYSSCP=LIN X64`).

Perhaps try the following, slightly different approach?

```
%let file = %sysfunc(pathname(work))/new.xml;

proc lua restart;
submit;
    local file_name = sas.symget("file")
    print (file_name)
    file = io.open (file_name, "w")
    io.output(file) -- sets default output
    io.write ("<test>", "\n")
    io.write ("write to file", "\n")
    io.write ("</test>", "\n")
    io.close(file)
endsubmit;
run;
```

Comment: I guess it must be windows related - definitely a support track, as it works for me on the exact same maintenance release.  I'm presuming you have `XCMD` enabled, and the system is not on lockdown?

Comment: I get the same traceback error on windows with 9.4M4 64 bit.   SYSVLONG=9.04.01M4P110916   Let us know what sas support says.